# Force python to fail when long/bigints are needed

Tags: python

Is there a way to disallow these in a program?

For example:

`x = 2**50  # expected to work (in a 64 bit binary)`

`x = x * x  # expected to fail/raise`

Reason: bigint operations are much slower than ints, but python switches from one to the other with no warning. I would like to know so I can focus optimization efforts.

I'm interested in python 2.7 (specifically pypy). I know that the handling of longs in python 3 is different.

Comment: Re: "but python switches from one to the other with no warning", how does it switch exactly? Python is not writing the code as far we know.

Comment: It switches according to the size of the number. In some computations you can't know ahead of time (without making the computation) what the end result size will be.

Comment: If you are worried about speed, you should probably be using NumPy instead of worrying about the difference between `int` and `long`.

Comment: pypy is adequately fast when it comes to ints. What are you saying exactly, that NumPy's bigint is faster than python's (pypy's)?

Comment: one way to do it, maybe only way is to review your code and check cariable size in each step and reaise error if an operation is next and size is such that long typecast will be done, but I dont recommend this

Comment: Because python allows reflection I was hoping for a solution more robust than code review, like "override `__builtins__.long`".